# Regarding base form for sdi window in win apps c#

Tags: c#

i have one MDI form and few SDI form. now i will create one base form for all the sdi form and write one function which will enable and disable control on my sdi form but i will not call that function explicitly from child sdi form. basically my all sdi will extend that base form. so please tell me is there any way that a particular function in base form will be called automatically after constructor call of my sdi form will finish.

another question is that can i access the control of child form or sdi form from the base form as a result i can enable & disable it. so please tell 2 way one is to call a function of base form automatically and for that how to write the code because from sdi i will not call that function explicitly like base.funcname() and another one how to access control on sdi form from the base form.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of your dervied class, you can call a method on the base class.

```
public class MyBaseForm : Form
{
    protected void SomeIntitializationMethod() {...}
}

public class MyDerivedForm : MyBaseForm
{

    public MyDerivedForm()
    {
        base.SomeInitializationMethod();
    }
}
```

You cannot have something in the base class execute after your derived constructor executes without explicitly calling it, so you are probably limited to this method.

For your second question, you can always access the `Controls` collection on the base form since it is part of the Form object.

Answer (score 1):

It "sounds like" you are trying to have the child SDI forms talk to the parent base form, in which case, try using events:

In the child SDI form:

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
  public delegate void DisableBaseHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
  public event DisableBaseHandler DisableBase;

  public ChildForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    OnDisableBase();
  }

  private void OnDisableBase()
  {
    if (DisableBase != null)
      DisableBase(this, new EventArgs());
  }
}
```

and in the parent Base form:

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
  private ChildForm _OtherForm;

  public BaseForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (_OtherForm == null || _OtherForm.IsDisposed)
    {
      _OtherForm = new ChildForm();
      _OtherForm.DisableBase += new ChildForm.DisableBaseHandler(DisableMe);
    }
    _OtherForm.Show();
  }

  private void DisableMe(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //Disable Base Controls...
    button1.Enabled = false;
  }
}
```